# File Decryption Problems

Tags: file-format, decryption, xor

over the past year, I provided an English patch to a community of thousands of players of a game I love and which is not available in English (just Chinese and Korean).

Sadly, besides me, other people created cheat tools for the game forcing and the developers to react by encrypting the files of the client.
Even tho I am happy they make an effort to prevent cheating, I am sad I can no longer provide the community with my English patch.

I spent the last few days trying to crack the files to be able to understand how I can decrypt them, replace the Chinese with my English content, and then encrypt it again.

However I was not lucky with this, the files are super weird.

we have tried to identify the structure and came up with

```
key (8byte) + filesize (4byte) + junk (0-6byte) + data
```

but we are not sure about the junk part

Here's an [encrypted new version](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/473414300971696142/473781792982171649/AccountProxy.txt) and a [decrypted old version](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/473414300971696142/473781898817175552/AccountProxy.txt) of the same file.
I picked this file as it seems to not have changed between encrypted and decrypted version.

Does anyone have any tips/pointers for me?

Comment: Are you sure about the files you attached? The sizes don't correlate by the pattern you mentioned.

Comment: that's what i meant, it looks weird.

we have tried some bruteforce xor encryption keys and on another file we were able to decrypt the first part which gave us 

autoImport("TestEffe

the rest was still scrambled

we are kinda lost on this :/ i am abit worried i have to close the english patch project

Comment: The normal file is larger in size than the encrypted version.

Comment: yes, one of our team noticed that it seems that there was a conversion happening which changed all CRLF at the end of each line to LF. maybe this is what you see.

Comment: mind sharing the name of the game? tried working with those files only but thinking about it, the "autoImport" could be coincidental. you can get any result by xoring a given string with the appropriate "key"

Comment: The behaviour is not exactly like multibyte xor cipher. Its somewhat algebraic though. Same input text result in almost same block(6/8 bytes are same). For encrypted text similar text offsets match with that in plaintext.
8f655d7f0f45 [160, 248]
296074eb0db4 [224, 376]
4b279b9268a7 [8, 56]
d56c6cde2f0e [32, 88]

untProxy [32, 88]
ccountPr [224, 376]
countPro [8, 56]
ountProx [160, 248]

Comment: we have more or less solved the riddle now.

they use a specific encryption library compiled as an armarbi64 .so file.
we are right now rewriting the functions to be able to use them on a x86 tool to try a decryption.

let's see if we can get it working ^^